# SSRS 2017 multi-select parameters not working for some users

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2017

For 50% of our users, multi-select options on reports do not render.  For affected users, drop down lists render as single-select lists.

- Issue is independent of browser (tried IE, Firefox, and Chrome)
- Issue is independent of operating sys (tried Windows 10 and Windows 7)
- Issue is independent of AD permissions (tried with admin user, and regular user)

Our SQL Server Version is 2017
Our server hardware is virtual (in cloud)

Comment: If multiselect works for user a on machine a and if multiselect does not work for user b on machine b.. then if user a and user b swap machines and try.. does it work? Checking to see if this is machine or user..

Comment: Try changing Data Source credentials.